# munin to monitor apache hits on particular URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, url, munin

We are having a problem with our web application, and are currently monitoring performance via munin. We have defined a list of URLs that are causing problems, and am hoping for munin to find out from the apache logs when those urls are being hit. Does anyone know how to set this up? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the exim plugins which parse the exim mail log.  It would make a good starting point for a custom plugin to monitory the apachelog.